# Is there a window with both a lower side lobe level and higher side lobe roll of rate than Blackman

Tags: window

Is there a window with both a lower side lobe level and higher side lobe roll of rate than the Blackman window - even if it is poor or useless for some other reason?

Comment: What research have you done? Wikipedia lists a whole lot of [window functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function). So does basically any signal processing text book.

Comment: Blackmann-Harris.  It's great for antialiasing as sidelobes get pushed very far down.  It's transition region is far from sharp though.

Comment: Thank you Andy. The Blackman Harris is better for side-lobe level but so much worse for roll-off. I need a window which is better against one but at least the equal for the other. Does that make sense?

Comment: [This answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/9231/4298) could be interesting for you.

Comment: Thanks Matt. I will check it out. Though I think the paper may not be there anymore. I will need to search for it.

Comment: I've updated the link; it's not a direct pdf-link, but at least you know the title and author, so you might be able to get of hold of it somewhere.

Comment: Matt; thank you again. It is early days for my testing, but that series of windows seems to be giving spectacular results. Greatly appreciated.